# Google Analytics - measurement protocol events not linking to other events

Tags: google-analytics

Problem: I need to see where users who download the app from the website, came from. We have google analytics(GA) and this part works well and we can see our traffic sources. However, I need to link users who install the app with those web visitors, so I can see from which channel, I get my "good users". The ones who ultimately install the app and set it up.

Solution Implemented: I have turned on the userID functionality and have session unification turned on. I am generating userIDs from the internal apis and publishing them to google analytics, the standard way. It is a PHP website and on session init, I make a call to the apis to get a new visitor id

```
$site_visitor_id = key_exists(static::USER_ID, $_SESSION) ? $_SESSION[static::USER_ID] : '';
$response = API::logWebVisitor(static::SITE_ID, $site_visitor_id, static::getClientIP());
            if (!is_null($response)
                && key_exists('data', $response)
                && key_exists('visitor_id', $response['data'])) {
                $_SESSION[static::USER_ID] = $response['data']['visitor_id'];
            } else {
                $_SESSION[static::USER_ID] = '';
            }
```

which is pushed to google analytics.

```
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', 'auto');
    ga('require', 'XXXXXX');
    ga('set', 'userId', '<?php echo $_SESSION[Session::USER_ID] ?>');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This works as I have all the users I would expect in the userID view in GA. One a user installs the app a user is created in our internal apis and the ip address is recorded. Every 10 minutes I try to link the generated userIDs ( which also have an ip address associated with it), with the users, based on the ip address. When I find a link, I push an install event to GA.

```
cid=<randstring>
&ea=Install
&ec=<category>
&el=InstallID
&ev=<install_id>
&t=event&
&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-Y
&uid=<mygenerated_user_id>
```

I can see the GA events perfectly fine and that works. One caveat though, is that the measurement protocol requires the cid, even though it says if the uid is passed this is not needed(fake news). So I just generate a random id to pass in and it works.

Issue: When I look in the reporting views of GA, GA is not linking these events to the web visitors that have the same user_id associated with it. Now, I can't see any of the user_ids to filter down and verify this as GA does not provide me with access to this information.

Expectations: I would expect that when I send an install event to GA with the user_id that GA sees that there are two client_ids with the same user_id and links those together, so I can see what channel lead me to getting that user. However, it's as if GA has no clue who that user_id is and never links them together. I am struggling to figure out what I need to look into to figure out why.

Any information around GA would be helpful as I don't know much about it and it's my first time using it.